# Rails ActiveRecord : scope incoherence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my model I have :

```
#models/friend.rb
scope :approved_friend, where(:approved => true)
```

And the Rails console outputs :

```
User.find(2).friends
 => [#<Friend id: 18, user_id: 2, approved: true, created_at: "2013-04-23 09:18:59", updated_at: "2013-04-23 09:18:59", friend_id: 1>] 

User.find(2).friends.approved_friend
=> []
```

Notice that approved is true in the output ...
Where it gets *crazy* is here :

```
User.find(1).friends.approved_friend
=> [#<Friend id: 19, user_id: 1, approved: true, created_at: "2013-04-23 09:19:36", updated_at: "2013-04-23 09:19:36", friend_id: 2>]
```

Am-I missing something ?

**EDIT :**
On one hand you have this query :

```
SELECT "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = 2

 => [#<Friend id: 18, user_id: 2, approved: true, created_at: "2013-04-23 09:18:59", updated_at: "2013-04-23 09:18:59", friend_id: 1>]
```

On the other hand, you've got this (query through scope) :

```
SELECT "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = 2 AND "friends"."approved" = 't'
 => []
```

Comment: You can check respective queries in log. Your scope is on friend model  and you are using it with user model.

Comment: Please restart your console session and post your logs here.

Comment: reload your console with the following command `reload!`

Comment: @Rubyman Yeah, the scope is on Friend but Friend belongs_to User :)

Comment: @Simpleton : has nothing to do with console; even RSpec fails.

Comment: @zakelfassi : can you check respective query in log file

Comment: @Rubyman Edited the post. The query is correct ... the result, is not !

Comment: Is the friend being created in a before block? If not, your attributes may be different? Also why aren't you using Ruby 1.9 syntax `where(approved: true)`?

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL?  In other words what actual value is being held in your approved coloumn? 1 and 0 or t

Comment: @Bala actually, it's database independent (true, 0, 1, 'true', ... is converted by ActiveRecord to TrueClass/FalseClass). But as you can see, another query renders correctly ...!

Comment: @Simpleton the code fails both in RSpec/FactoryGirl (in a before :each), and in Rails console. The attributes are the very same. (as for the syntax, just an ol' school personal pref :)

Comment: Try appending the scoped where clause in the query and not calling it through the scope to confirm if it returns your object (and to make sure the SQL is the same as in the scope). Also, try putting the scoped code in a lamdba to see if there's any difference in the output.

Comment: @Simpleton both done ... no success :/ I believe this is the single most mind-bugging bug I've encountered in 10+ years in this field. Weird.

Comment: Can you confirm by looking at the SQL (log) that ActiveRecord's TrueClass/FalseClass conversion represents the correct datatype of the actual value of your model.

Comment: @Bala yep - all datatypes are correct, unfortunately.

Comment: Running out of ideas, check out your database cleaning in your spec_helper. It could be some weird validation logic, otherwise try before(:all) instead of before(:each) to eliminate that possibility too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the :status field is in the Friend model, you might have to change the scope to this

scope :approved_friend, where('friends.approved' => true).includes(:friend)

Comment: The scope is in friend.rb, needless to do this (though, I've tested it. Same thing).